# Is there Google Location API or other API for Location Autocomplete without Map?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, google-places-api

I know about [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) library but it shows map as well. All I want a textbox that then shows location in a dropdown after search.

Comment: Might be close to what you're after. displaying the map seems optional. http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/

Comment: Have you try `AutocompleteService`? Documentation says that it does not display UI element.

Comment: Place autocomplete works without map as well. As shown in this sample: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform